# Dim_Date SSIS Business Intelligence

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

I want to create two dim_Table Tables

```
dim-Temp_Start(id_Temp_Start,year,trimestre,month,week,day)
dim-Temp_End(id_Temp_End,year,trimestre,month,week,day)
```

How can I load these tables from a calendar?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_TEMP_FIN]( 
[ID_TEMP_FIN] [int] NOT NULL, 
[ANNEE] [int] NULL, 
[TRIMESTRE] [int] NULL, 
[MOIS] [int] NULL, 
[SEMAINE] [int] NULL, 
[JOUR] [int] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_TEMP_FIN] PRIMARY KEY 
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_TEMP_DEBUT]( 
[ID_TEMP_DEB] [int] NOT NULL, 
[ANNEE] [int] NULL, 
[TRIMESTRE] [int] NULL, 
[MOIS] [int] NULL, 
[SEMAINE] [int] NULL, 
[JOUR] [int] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_TEMP_DEBUT] PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Comment: Can you show us what did you try?

Comment: i have just create tables and i ask if there is a way or composant on SSIS that can load dim_Data CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_TEMP_FIN](
 [ID_TEMP_FIN] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ANNEE] [int] NULL,
 [TRIMESTRE] [int] NULL,
 [MOIS] [int] NULL,
 [SEMAINE] [int] NULL,
 [JOUR] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_TEMP_FIN] PRIMARY KEY ) and CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_TEMP_DEBUT](
 [ID_TEMP_DEB] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ANNEE] [int] NULL,
 [TRIMESTRE] [int] NULL,
 [MOIS] [int] NULL,
 [SEMAINE] [int] NULL,
 [JOUR] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_TEMP_DEBUT] PRIMARY KEY)

Comment: Load = fill with some ranges of dates?

Comment: sorry for my english :s yes fill dates from Calendar

Comment: You said you wanted two tables named dim-temp_start and end but then you wanted them named dim_temp_fin and debut instead? Or is if four tables? Explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: thank you ,i found the solution on this link 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3V-9_SN3AXk
best regards,